# Relevancy tuning solr fulltext search by keyword position + occurrence?

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I'm trying to do text searching on dictionary definitions which are stored in an array of each word. What I want to do is have the following conditions to be ranked higher:

1. If the keyword appears early in the definitions, the entry should be ranked higher.
2. If the definition fully matches the keyword, the entry should be ranked higher.
3. If the keyword appears more often in the definitions, the entry should be ranked higher.

For example, search for "car".

Word1:

1. Car
2. Vehicle
3. Bus

Word 2:

1. Parking a car
2. Carpark

Word 3:

1. Small car

The ranking should return Word1, then Word 3, then Word 2.

How would I implement this with Solr, if at all possible? If not, what other options do I have for this kind of search ranking?

Comment: Why would Word 3 come ahead of Word 2?

Comment: "car" is the 2nd word in "small car", where as in word 2 "parking a car" is 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

I have only analyzed this academically, so cannot back my answer with experience.

Have a look at [Payloads](http://searchhub.org/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) in Solr. Grant Ingersoll explains it at a basic level, and the article has tests that look similar to your use case.

[Spanquery](http://searchhub.org/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/) is also worth checking out, but am not sure if it fits the use case you describe.

Do post back with your experiments/experiences.